# IE9 triggers img element onerror event when too many images

Tags: javascript, html, image, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

**Problem**

The problem is that `<img> onerror` is trigerring in `IE9` when there are already too many images on the page even though images are properly loaded. Too many images is actually around `100 - 200 images` of around `1600 x 2300`. I can't post a fiddle since I don't have 200 URLs for images like this so anyone interested, I have a favor to ask and replicate on you local machine.

Testing this issue might be a little tedious so please bear with me sirs. I will give a little bounty for this because of it's hassle haha.

**Prerequisites** (**EDIT:** see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j4eE7/1/) instead)

1. Any image preferably around 1600 by 2300 (mine is about 800KB) and IE9 (didn't test any other IE yet sorry, maybe you can try)
2. Name that image `1.jpg` and save in any empty folder
3. Copy and paste that image 200 times (100 may do it, but to be safe) on the same folder.
4. By now you should get file names like `1 - Copy (x).jpg`, where `x` is `0 - 200`.
5. In the same folder, make an html file with the code below.

**Code**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                var i = 0;

                $("#btn").click(function() {
                    var str = "";
                    var limit = i + 20;

                    $("div.toBeHidden").hide();

                    str += "<div class='toBeHidden'>"
                    for( ; i < limit && i < 200 ; i++) {
                        str += "<img src='1 - Copy (" + i + ").jpg' alt='Not found' onerror='console.log(\"too bad\");' height='50' width='50'/>";
                    }
                    str += "</div><br/>"

                    $("#container").append(str);
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="button" id="btn" value="Test"/>
        <div id="container">

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

If you are able to replicate it, you should there should be prints `"Too bad"` in your console the `3rd or 4th time` you press the "Test" button. What's worse is that after the first "Too bad" anything after is triggering `onerror`.

Comment: So each click of the button adds two images, and you are clicking 3 or 4 times, meaning 600 to 800 images. Correct? I am unable to replicate your issue. I built http://jsfiddle.net/pQ7Ag/2/ to assist in producing the issue, but didn't get the results you're experiencing. Output the image `src` in the console and see if the results are consistent across refreshes.

Comment: Thanks so much for the fiddle! Each button click just adds a `<div>` with `20` new images, and hides all previous `<div>` (with images). I'll test this fiddle once I am at the workplace (8-10hrs from now) since I don't have IE9 here at home.

Comment: @JonathanSampson, thanks for the tip about lorempixel.com sir, I added a fiddle with that and I can replicate it in IE9. Some images after 4th click doesn't load and triggers `onerror`/ Maybe, the page is already full of images?

@Progo, I should I could. But it is a requirement.

Answer (score 1):

The loop in your code snippet shows 200 iterations, not 20, so on the 3rd or 4th click, you have added between 500-600 images.

I suspect that IE9 has a limit (maybe 2^9 = 512?) on resources it allows at once.

I'd suggest removing old images from the DOM once they have been scrolled out of view. The user will only see a few images at once, so you can optimize your page to be more memory efficient (mobile users will be grateful).

Comment: `for( ; i < limit && i < 200 ; i++) {` Actually it's just 20, please see the condition again. And yeah, the partial solution I found so far involves removing it from the DOM but not on scroll but based on the example, when the containing `<div>` is hidden. The problem right now is how to release the allocated memory when the obj is still referenced in JS.

Answer (score 0):

sir why dont u disable onerror

```
this.onerror=null;
```

Comment: Because I need it. I just don't want it to execute when not it's not supposed to.

Answer (score 0):

As an option you may try to modify the `src` attribute values of `<img>` elements instead of replacing whole DOM fragment to solve memory issues.

For the infinite scroll you can also reuse these fragments, just need to have several of them in memory and switch when needed.